# null point exception if not having value in array

Tags: java, arrays

Client:

```
for(int j=0;j<prod10.length;j++){
            String ret_val ="";
            bean.setProd10(prod10[j]);
            ret_val=build.saveRSupplier(bean);

        }
```

DAO:

```
if(rs.next()){
                String sum=rs.getString("max(patient_no)+1");
                String q7="insert into new8(ok, reference)"
                        + " values('"+sum+"','"+purid10+"')";
                PreparedStatement p7 = con.prepareStatement(q7);
                int s7 = p7.executeUpdate();        
            }
```

if i put value in array then by using prod10 it set the length and array of data are stored in the database but if i do not put value in array null point exception occur,this should not have to happen what i should have to do for this

Comment: I presume your `prod10` array is `null`. Have a null check before the for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your `prod10` array is `null`. Have a null check before the for loop.

```
if(null != prod10) {
for(int j=0;j<prod10.length;j++){
            String ret_val ="";
            bean.setProd10(prod10[j]);
            ret_val=build.saveRSupplier(bean);

        }
}
```

Comment: @scor. You are welcome. You can accept my answer if it worked for you.